# [Docker][Maven] How to add a local maven project as dependency to another maven project?

Tags: java, maven, docker, docker-compose

There are two maven projects - **proejct1** and **project2**.

`com.project1.Object1.class` depends on `com.project2.Object2.class`, I want to add project2 as dependency to project1.

I know under certain IDE (such as Itellij) this is easy to setup, and I'm using IDE set-ups for development. But for production, I need to build project1 independent from any IDE-environment.

Also I'm using **Docker**. It would be nice if there is a way to simplify this problem in Docker.

```
- root
  - project1
    - src
      - com.project1.Object1.class
    - pom.xml
    - Dockerfile
  - project2
    - src
      - com.project2.Object2.class
    - pom.xml
    - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: Use another Docker container to host a Maven repository ;)

Answer (score 0):

You reference different Maven projects in your pom.xml. If you build project2 with  `install`, you can reference it (locally) from project1. If you use a repository like Nexus or Artifactory, you deploy project2 there and reference it from project1.